# How to split one big rectangle on N smaller rectangles to look random?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, boost

How to split one big rectangle on N smaller rectangles to look random ?
I need to generate couple divisions for different value of n.
Is there library for this in boost for c++ or some for python ?

Comment: Is it okay if every rectangle has the same width or height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One* rectangle can be divided into *two* rectangles by drawing either a horizontal or a vertical line. Divide one of those rectangles and the result is *three* rectangles. Continue until you have *N* rectangles.  Some limitations to observe to improve the results

- Don't divide a rectangle with a horizontal line if the height is
  below some threshold
- Don't divide a rectangle with a vertical line if the width is below
  some threshold
- Divide by quarters, thirds, or halves, i.e. avoid 90/10 splits
- Keep a list of rectangles sorted by area, and always divide the
  rectangle with the largest area